# Django 1.9 Installation SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to install django 1.9 in my Ubuntu Box (14.04 LTS) with virtualenv enabled. but I got this wired installation problem.

```
(venv)nix1947$ pip install django
Downloading/unpacking django
  Downloading Django-1.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.6MB): 6.6MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: django
*** Error compiling '/home/nix1947/projects/newsportal/venv/build/django/django/conf/app_template/apps.py'...
  File "/home/nix1947/projects/newsportal/venv/build/django/django/conf/app_template/apps.py", line 4
    class {{ camel_case_app_name }}Config(AppConfig):
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

*** Error compiling '/home/nix1947/projects/newsportal/venv/build/django/django/conf/app_template/models.py'...
  File "/home/nix1947/projects/newsportal/venv/build/django/django/conf/app_template/models.py", line 1
    {{ unicode_literals }}from django.db import models
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Successfully installed django
Cleaning up...
```

Is this the problem in django source code ? or am I missing something ?

the python that I have used is python3 in virtualenv which is enabled by 
`virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 venv` command and the version of pip that I am using is

```
pip 1.5.4 from /home/nix1947/projects/newsportal/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
```

and virtualenv version is

```
(venv)nix1947$ virtualenv --version
1.11.4
```

What is the problem, Can someone guide me

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a common issue caused by an outdated version of setuptools (5.5.x):

> When installing Django 1.9+ with setuptools 5.5.x, you’ll see:
>
> ```
> Compiling django/conf/app_template/apps.py ...   File
> "django/conf/app_template/apps.py", line 4
>     class {{ camel_case_app_name }}Config(AppConfig):
>           ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> Compiling django/conf/app_template/models.py ...   File
> "django/conf/app_template/models.py", line 1
>     {{ unicode_literals }}from django.db import models
>                              ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```
>
> It’s safe to ignore these errors (Django will still install just fine), but you
>   can avoid them by upgrading setuptools to a more recent version. If
>   you’re using pip, you can upgrade pip using pip install -U pip which
>   will also upgrade setuptools.
>
> (Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#syntaxerror-when-installing-django-setuptools-5-5-x)

---

The solution is to **upgrade pip** first (which also upgrades setuptools) and then install django again:

```
pip install -U pip
pip install django
```

Comment: If I need to create another virtualenv, I should upgrade pip each time isn't. so it would be better If I upgrade my system pip and install the django in virtuale env

Comment: You can either do that or just ignore these errors. (It's safe to ignore them as stated in the link i provided).

Comment: ok got it, I should probably ignore those error for this project, and when I create another venve I will considering on upgrade the pip, But I have apply the upgrade to system pip using `sudo apt-get upgrade python-pip` let us hope this will solve the problem for all venv, so I don't need to do `pip install -U pip` for each venv